# RegExp to extract values from a string within quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a way to extract parameters that are within quotes from a string.

The goal is to take an expression like:

```
function1("var1","var2","var3","function2("func2Var1","func2Var2"))
```

And extract the variables:

```
var1
var2
var3
function2("func2Var1","func2Var2")
```

Comment: Your quotes are not balanced because you're missing one before the last `)`.

Comment: Is seams that your Regex should be much smarter than just searching for quotes. It should also know about commas and parentheses, and how all these interact together.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do. First I recommend you to download and install "Expresso" from the following link, it's a free app, "registerware". It is a testground for regular expressions (not tied to .NET but is a .net app), that allows you make and test regular expressions on an ide-like environment. It also have tutorials.

It's default expression, for testing, is to get date components separated by slashes.

You can start with something like this: 
(?([a-zA-Z]\w*)\s+)+(?([a-zA-Z]\w*)+)\s*((?(\"(?[^"]+)\"),\s*)+(\"(?[^"]+)\")\s*)

However, you should not try to parse like your item 4 nested quote styles as is difficult to know, for a computer, when to start ot stop.

However, for this kind of project, I would recommend a state machine which is best suited for compilers.